# Unnecessary data in the urls Google Analytics

Tags: php, url, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have setup Google Analytics tracking code in my project.
Now, I want to check, how many users have hit a certain url on my website.
The url parameters varies for user to user. And I want to group them under just one main sub url.

What I have tried is setting up all the parameters that Google Analytics will exclude, while gathering this information: Using **Exclude URL Query Parameters** text box.

Suppose this is my URL:

> www.example.com/petDetails?petType=Cat&PetColor=Black similarly
>
> www.example.com/petDetails?petType=Dog&PetColor=white

So group the above urls inside only

> '/petDetails'

This works fine for few urls. But I found some strange data like

> www.example.com/petDetails#1102petType=Cat&PetColor=Black
>
> www.example.com/petDetails#45654petType=Dog&PetColor=white

Please pay attention to the **#someNumber** part. Nowhere in the code, I add such kind of number with # appended.

There are loads of such urls in the report in GA, and these are not grouped inside

> '/petDetails'

thus creating unique entry for each.

How do I eliminate this problem.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need more data on this, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Nowhere in the code, I add such kind of number with # appended.

Looks like you have anchor tags on your site that point to hashtags/fragments.  It's used for being able to navigate to specific points on your page.

Perhaps you didn't explicitly make links on your page that point to them though it's highly unlikely that you didn't.

But, it's also easy enough for a visitor to for example look at a section/header of your page and see that there is an id='foo' attribute and then just add '#foo' to the URL to go directly to it.

But that's far less likely than the first scenario where you do in fact have links like this (or a framework that utilizes it for navigation).

In any case, if you want to ensure that the reported URI only has the path, no query string or hash, I suggest you create a filter to strip them.

Go into Google Analytics and navigate to the Admin/Config for the View and click on **Filters**, and click on the red **+ New Filter** button.

Choose **Create new Filter** radio button.

For **Filter Name** name it something like "URI - strip query,hash"

For **Filter Type**, select **Custom** and then select **Advanced** radio button.

For **Field A -> Extract A**, select "Request URI" and then in the text field, put the following: `^([^?#]+)`

Leave **Field B -> Extract B** blank; you don't need it.

For **Output To -> Constructor**, select "Request URI" and then in the text field, put the following: `$A1`

In the checkboxes after that, make sure The following are checked:
**Field A Required**, and **Override Output Field**.

Finally, **Save** the filter.

[image]

**Edit:**

> Thanks a ton @Crayon, for the detailed steps. It worked!. But will you
>   be please kind to explain the Output To-> Constructor field? I can't
>   seem to understand it.

Okay so the **Advanced Custom Filter** is a way for you to push stuff from one item to another. It gives you the ability to populate (or override) stuff without making changes to your site code. So in the scenario above, it is used to modify the reported URI.  Another common scenario is prefixing the URI with the hostname, for views that have pages on multiple domains.

So basically what you can do is in the **Field A** and **Field B**, use regex to match what you want from the specified source. Part of regex syntax is grouping part (or all) of the pattern (by putting parenthesis around the portion of the pattern), and you can reference the captured group later.

GA has special syntax for referencing this because of its interface/setup conventions.  So `$A` is the prefix to reference the captured groups in **Field A**.  Then the number after that is which captured group, e.g. `$A1` references the first captured group in **Field A**.  In your scenario above, we only use one field and we only have one captured group.

Ultimately, all this will go into the **Overwrite to** field, which is the field you want to pop (or override) with a value (in this scenario, the URI), and the  **Constructor** is what you are overwriting it with.

So overall, we take the current URI, use regex pattern `^([^?#]+)` match only up to the first `?` (query string delimiter) or `#` (hash/fragment delimiter) whichever comes first and capture that as group `$A1`.  Then we overwrite the URI with that value, which effectively strips the URI of that stuff.

*sidenote: I see a lot of people (myself included, when I was new to it) get confused about the Advanced Custom Filter. IMO it would be easier to understand if GA were to change the foo->bar labels for the form fields to be properly aligned labels, and relabel them to something e.g. "New Value" instead of "Constructor".*

Comment: Thanks a ton @Crayon, for the detailed steps. It worked!. But will you be please kind to explain the Output To-> Constructor field? I can't seem to understand it.